# Cordova Geolocation returning NAN for latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, html, windows, cordova, geolocation

So I'm new to javascript and Cordova and I'm trying to create a simple GPS app in Visual Studio 2015 that just gets my current position when I click the "CURRENT POSITION".

It works when I test it in Firefox, but not when I try to run it on my local machine or on the remote machine. (I'm using Windows 10 and testing on a Panasonic FZ-M1 Toughpad. When I run it on the local/remote machine the latitude and longitude return NAN after around 30 seconds.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <title>gpsCordova</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2>Touch Me.</h2>
    <button id="locationButton">CURRENT LOCATION</button><br>
    <p id="Geolocation"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>

</body>
```

```
document.getElementById("locationButton").addEventListener("click", getLocation);

var geoLoc = document.getElementById("Geolocation");
var geolocationOptions = {
enableHighAccuracy: true,
maximumAge: 3600000
}

function getLocation() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError, geolocationOptions);
}

function geolocationSuccess(position) {

geoLoc.innerHTML ="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
"<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude +
"<br>Accuracy: " + position.coords.accuracy +
"<br>Altitude: " + position.coords.altitude +
"<br>Altitude Accuracy: " + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy +
"<br>Heading: " + position.coords.heading +
"<br>Speed: " + position.coords.speed +
"<br>Timestamp: " + position.coords.timestamp + "<br>";

}

function geolocationError(error) {
geoLoc.innerHTML = "Failure" +
   "<br>error: " + error.name +
   "<br>message: " + error.message;
    }
```

I'm not sure what else to add, but does anyone have any experience with this issue? Or is there something that I'm missing in my code?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you check if the test device has geolocation enabled and if the app has the correct geolocation permission from the OS?

Comment: Yes the device has geolocation enabled. 
I'm not sure what you mean by the app has the correct geolocation permission from the OS, but under the device settings, the permission for location for the app is on. When I run the app I select yes when it prompts me to share location.

Comment: Hi @mmm121 under iOS each app needs to be confirmed to use geolocation, the same is true for Android v5 and up. I mean did you double check this permission is actually given to the app (if applicable). Otherwise your code looks good and similar to code I used successfully with Cordova in the past.

Comment: Yes geolocation is confirmed under the app. I'm using a Windows 10 tablet, I don't know if that would make a difference.

Comment: @mmm121 how did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Features provided by this plugin are not available until after the deviceready event.

> https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation